# Move an image from Photos macOS app to trash programmatically

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, photos

I want to remove a photo(move to Recently Deleted Album) from Photos macOS app using swift and MediaLibrary framework.

MediaLibrary framework provides read-only acces to Photos Library on mac so I belive it wont help and I can't find any other framework who provides read and write acces like Photos framework does for iOS.

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Please don't include irrelevant tags. Your question clearly states that you require an answer in Swift, why use the Obj-C tag then?

Comment: I require an answer in Swift, but if someone has an answer in Obj-C Icould transform the code because is very simple and I worked in Obj-C for some time. Any answer is better that none

Comment: See what AppleScript can do for Photos.

Comment: @ElTomato According to Photos' AppleScript dictionary, only folders and albums can be deleted, not photos themselves. I'm not sure that there is a way to do this.

Comment: There are some applications that do that. They move the images that want to be deleted into a new album(which has the Recently Deleted album's functionality ) and then the user cand delete the images from the new album and images will dissapear from all the albums.